# Add JSON object to JSON file using JQ

Tags: json, jq

Given the following JSON file (sample.json)

```
{
  "api": "3.0.0",
  "data": {
    "description": "something",
    "title": "hello",
    "version": "1.0",
    "app": {
      "name": "abc",
      "id": "xyz"
    }
  }
}
```

I wish to add the following JSON object at root level to the file above:

```
{
  "heading": {
    "user": ["$username"]
  }
}
```

Where `$username` is a Bash variable.

Is there a better way to achieve this than the following?

`blob=$(jq -n --arg foo API_NAME '{"heading": {"user": [env.username]}}')`

`jq --argjson obj "$(echo $blob)" '. + $obj' < sample.json`

Comment: [Useless echo? Instead of 'cmd $(echo foo)' just use 'cmd foo'](https://www.shellcheck.net/wiki/SC2116)

Answer (score 2):

Just move what you create as `blob` directly into the other filter, ending up with just one jq call:

```bash
jq --arg username "$username" '. + {heading: {user: [$username]}}' sample.json
```